# How to add PayPal library Code with my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone

How to add PayPal library Code with my iPhone  application?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Have you actually read the documentation that comes with the SDK or played with the sample project ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the paypal objective c library on google , you will find the objective c classes to use for paypla payment . What exactly do want to do ? Can ypu explain it in details ?